# mongoose didn't fire save-callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-connection

I am very confused.
The installed mongoose-module (latest) didn't fire the save callback.

I have defined the following schema:

```
var Object = new global.db.Schema({
  customerId: { type: String, required: true },
  customerPrefix: { type: String, required: true },
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  fields: { type: Array, default: [] },
  // ... (other fields have default values) 
});
```

global.db is mongoose (server.js):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/dbName');
var connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.on('error', function(dbError) {
    console.log(dbError); // no errors happend 
});

connection.once('open', function() {
    global.db = mongoose;
    global.models = require('./lib/dao');
});
```

global.models contains the models (lib/dao/)

```
module.exports = global.db.model('Object', dbObjectSchema);
```

Now I try to create a new document:

```
var newObject = new global.models.Object({});
newObject.customerId = data.customerId;
newObject.customerPrefix = data.prefix;
newObject.fields = data.fields;
newObject.name = data.name;

console.log(global.db.connection.host); // localhost
console.log(global.db.connection.port); // 27017
// i've tested also whether i can call .find (it works and callback will fired!)
newObject.save(function(err) {
   // this part will never called
   console.log("save callback fired"); 
   if (typeof callback == 'function') {
      callback(err, newObject);
   }
});
```

I absolutely do not understand why the callback is not fired.
To test some known issues (eg. connection not etablished, ...)
I already have inserted some debug-outputs, but everything looks fine :(

Can anyone help me? :/

Best regards

Comment: First and foremost, `var Object = ` Don't do this :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Comment: Couple of things you can try. Can you save/update using the native mongo driver? This might indicate whether you have the correct permissions (since you seem to be able to read). Is your object saved anyway (despite of the callback not being fired)?

Comment: @Edo no the document will not been saved but it could happend because a validation error occurs. i've tried it with .find and it works the callback will be fired. but save is not working. actually i must have full permissions (it works in other applications on the same way)

Comment: It's up to you, but if I were in your position, I'd test to see whether I would be able to write using the native driver. Since it seems you have the database connection setup properly...

Comment: connection.collection('customobjects').insert([{ ... }], function(err, result) {}); works! but what is the reason? how can i fix it to use my model? :/

Comment: solution found: i think i have overwritten a method of an mongoose doc (schema.methods.validate). Once i removed the declaration of validate, it works.